# Compare Array numbers with DF column. If exists in df, than write to new df

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, jupyter

I have the following problem:
I have an array with multiple ID's and i also have a column in a df, with which I want to match these ID's.
If equal, the row should be written to a new DF.

This is my array, called manhatten_ids

```
array([  4,  12,  13,  24,  41,  42,  43,  45,  48,  50,  68,  74,  75,
    79,  87,  88,  90, 100, 103, 104, 105, 107, 113, 114, 116, 120,
   125, 127, 128, 137, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 148, 151, 152, 153,
   158, 161, 162, 163, 164, 166, 170, 186, 194, 202, 209, 211, 224,
   229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 236, 237, 238, 239, 243, 244, 246,
   249, 261, 262, 263], dtype=int64)
```

This is my frame, called df_trips:

[image: This is my frame, called df_trips:]

so if one DOLocation ID matches an array value, it should write the whole row with all columns to a new df, called newdf.

This one actually does not work:

```
newdf=df.loc[df_trips['DOLocationID'].isin(manhatten_ids)]
```

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: `newdf['column name']=df.loc[df['column'].isin(array),'column name']`?

Comment: i want to compare the df column with the array values.. but after it should save the whole row with all features to the new frame

Comment: Please include a [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample data and expected output.

Comment: okay it is in now

Comment: `df` should be `df_trips` no? `new_df = df_trips.loc[df_trips['DOLocationID'].isin(manhattan_ids)]`

Comment: This is still not an MRE, so it is hard for us to reproduce the problem. `df.loc[df['DOLocationID'].isin(manhatten_ids)]` might not work, if your DOLocationID column is not numerical, but an object (usually this means strings in pandas). You have to use isin with the same or similar object types.

Answer (score 0):

So we can do this iteratively by using the enumerate function two look through the values of the location column like so:

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame()
row_ind = 0 #row of new dataframe that you will write on

vals = df.DOLocationID.values #get values of location column
for i, val in enumerate(vals):
    if val in manhatten_ids: #check if location val is in manhatten ids
        newdf.loc[row_ind] = df.iloc[i] #assign new row of newdf to current row in df
        row_ind += 1
```